# how to put in the top as a ad My website in google?

Tags: google-app-engine

I need to put in the top of My website address when user search in google. (as a green color link). see following example https://www.google.lk/search?q=shuttle+service&oq=shuttle+service&gs_l=serp.1.0.0l10.8879.15428.0.16983.15.10.0.5.5.0.262.1599.0j5j3.8.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..2.13.1630...35i39k1j0i67k1j0i131k1j0i10k1.mVKUSLo_npU

how can do it?

Answer (score 0):

> You can't. Google programmatically determines that a page contains a likely answer to the user's question, and displays the result as a featured snippet.

Source: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6229325?hl=en-LK

Comment: actually I need put an Ad.....My web address (green color Ad in google)

Comment: Then the service you are looking for is [AdWords](https://adwords.google.com/home/?channel=ha&sourceid=awo&subid=us-en-ha-aw-bkhvm-kwd-12340363-103694652005&gclid=CIm7_Yie-NACFRmewAod_hQGAg&dclid=CPDYl4me-NACFYZRAQodnqICrA)